# Create new route after checking path from server side in react router dom v6.9

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
let staticPages = {
  '/': {
    'title': "Home Title",
    'layout': <Home />
  },
  '/contact': {
    'title': "Contact Title",
    'layout': 'Contact'
  },
  '/about': {
    'title': "About Title",
    'layout': 'About'
  },
  '/login': {
    'title': "Login Title",
    'layout': <Login />
  }
}
```

```
function App(){
  const location = useLocation()
  const [config, setConfig] = useState({
    "title": "Postify",
    "path": location.pathname
  })

  const isPathUser = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_USER_API}/is-user`, {
      username: config.path
    })
    .then((res) => resolve(res.data))
  })

  const getLayoutByPath = (path) => {
    let roots = []
    Object.entries(staticPages).map((val, key) => {
      roots.push({ path: val[0], element: val[1].layout })
    });
    if(!staticPages.hasOwnProperty(path)){
      isPathUser
      .then((res) => {
        res
        ? roots.push({ path: path, element: <User /> })
        : roots.push({ path: path, element: <NotFound /> })
      })
    }
    return roots;
  }

  return(
    <>
      {
        useRoutes(getLayoutByPath(config.path))
      }
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

I defined the getLayoutByPath function which generates all the roots as `{ path: path, element: layout }` and returns them in a cumulative way to the useRoutes function. It works without any problem when the incoming path value matches an index in the static variable. But if the incoming path value does not match the static variable, I need to check if it is a user and if the value is user  not . I need to create a route using these two elements.

When I run the code above and the path value is a value that needs to be checked, I get the following error in the console 'routes matched location **"/beytullah"**' and there is a blank page on the screen.

http://localhost:3000/beytullah

Long story short, if the path value doesn't exist in the static pages variables, I should check if it is used or not and create a new Route with return  or  elements in react-router-dom